# jupyter ipywidgets doesn't show function return value

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, jupyter, ipywidgets

I used the most simply example :

```
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
from IPython.display import display


# this is a sample function
def myfunc(x):
    display(x*2) # I add this for testing
    print(x*2)  # I add this for testing
    return x*2

interact(myfunc,x=widgets.IntSlider(min=-10,max=10,value=0))
```

while sliding slider, no output .

[image]

But same example in [here](http://queirozf.com/entries/interactive-controls-for-jupyter-notebooks-python-examples) does show output :
 [image]

How do I fix jupyter to show the output ?

Comment: What are you running your python code in? It doesn't look like Jupyter notebook...?

Comment: @ac24 it is jupyter notebook with a dark theme .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find this was caused by `Limit Output` extension

[image]

Parameters :

[image]

Though limit char number is: 100000, still affected ipywidgets .

Disable this work it out :

[image]